# After jarring images do not show

Tags: java, image, graphics, jar

```
public class LidPop extends Projectile
{
private int x;
private int y;
private int l = 3;
private int h = 18;
private int dx = -3;
private Image i;

public LidPop(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    String rootPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String imgPath = rootPath + File.separator + "src/pics/lidPop.png" + File.separator;
    try 
    {                
        i = ImageIO.read(new File(imgPath));
    } catch (IOException ex) 
    {
          System.out.println("not working");
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(i, x, y, x+l, y+h, 0, 0, l, h, null);
}
```

When I jar the code and run it the image that is loaded is not show but I know its is there because the player is still be hit by it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

You can't load files directly from `jar` file using `File`. You can use `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/src/pics/lidPop.png");`

it will returns `InputStream`.

Am assuming `lidPop.png` is in jar with `src/pics/lidPop.png` path.

Modify `ImageIO.read()` method to accept `InputStream`.

Comment: how would i use that or where?

Comment: so that did not work it still does not show after jarring but works in eclipse.

Comment: @ZergRushJoe can you specify exact path of `src/pics/lidPop.png`? do you want to load file from `jar` file??

Comment: confirm me the path for `lidPop.png` file in jar file?

Comment: C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\eclipse\wksp\RTSGame\src\pics is the full path form eclipse

Comment: No i want path in generated `jar` file?

Comment: @ZergRushJoe upated the answer. check once

Comment: @ZergRushJoe - are you sure the png is in jar at all ? Try to extract the jar (it's just a regular zipfile) and see if the file is in `src/pics/lidPop.png`

Comment: I guess you could use `pics/lidPop.png` instead of `src/pics/lidPop.png`.

Comment: If you are using Linux use `unzip file.zip -d destination_folder`

Comment: Rump.jar\pics I got it i had to re-download winrar

Comment: I figured it out i copy the images and put them in a folder called src and then made another folder pics and put the images in there and they display.